# Выполнение скрипта от имени другого пользователя

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos, shell

**Ситуация:**

Есть 2 пользователя:

- `sv_user`
- `user`

Под `user` можно выполнить `sudo su - sv_user` **без запроса пароля** (пароля от `sv_user` нет)

Есть доступ по ssh, с приватным ключом `user` (от *key* пароль есть); но нет пароля от `user` (т.е. подключиться можно, но выполнить `sudo -u` не получается, т.к. запрашивает пароль)

Я могу запустить `script.sh` находясь в оболочке `sv_user`, но нужно запустить выполнение `script.sh` от имени `sv_user`, находясь в оболочке `user`

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, это можно сделать?

Comment: Не могу разобраться, `su - user` == `su -l user` == `su --login user` ?

Если да, то можно задать права на выполнение, используя `sudo` именно `su - user`, но не `su -l user` или `su --login user` ?

Comment: Что-то у вас накручено странного. По хорошему надо бы разобраться с sudoers. А по простому можно попрбовать `sudo su -c '/path/to/script.sh' sv_user`

Comment: `sudo su -c '/path/to/script.sh' sv_user` - запрашивает пароль. Проблему решил:

- В скрипт добавил строчку `sudo su - sv_user`
- И запускаю `bash < /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: На просмотр `sudoers` нет прав, ни у `user`, ни у `sv_user`. Решение нашел, и это главное. Но смущает добавление строки в скрипт, хотелось бы придумать, как обойтись без этого, думаю можно с `heredoc` сделать

Comment: `sudo su -c '/path/to/script.sh' sv_user - запрашивает пароль.`. а `sudo su sv_user -c script.sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Итоговое решение** (для универсальности через `heredoc`):

```
bash <<'EOF'
sudo su - sv_user
/path/to/script.sh
EOF
```